# Повышается нагрузка на процессор при kill'е программы

Tags: golang

Из главной программы запускается подпрограмма: `err = e.command.Start()`, эта подпрограмма должна работать пока из главной на неё не придёт kill `err := e.command.Process.Kill()`, это работает и продпрограмма убивается, но когда это происходит нагрузка на ЦП от основной программы резко увеличивается. Подскажите в чём может быть дело. Всё в одной горутине.

Comment: Какая ОС? Как измеряется "нагрузка на ЦП основной программы"?

Comment: ОС Linux, Elementary OS. нагрузку смотрю в консольной утилите top.

Answer (score 1):

Проблемма решена. Раньше я сохранял *Cmd возвращаемой функцией `exec.Command()` в поле структуры. Я это убрал и проблемма решилась. Теперь я сохраняю только PID процесса и все системные вызовы отправляю через следующую конструкцию

```
process, err := os.FindProcess(pid)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = process.Signal(syscall.SIGKILL)
```

Возможно это связано с областью видимости или ещё чем-то. Если у вас есть мысли по чему так буду рад узнать